# Assembly practise understanding what happens with push command

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, cpu-registers

We have a practice in our course for using assembly which goes like this.
What is saved in the EAX register after this code?

```
mov eax, 10
push eax
push 20
mov ecx, eax
pop eax
```

So from what I understood is the first line means that 10 is put into the EAX and in the second line EAX is pushed to the stack.

But what does it mean? Does the contents of eax get erased?
If 20 is also pushed to the stack the stack is 10 and 20?

Will EAX register after the code be something like 10, 10, 20 or something else and how is it formatted?

Comment: `push` merely duplicates the content replicating it onto the stack; there is no modification of the source (just memory written, and stack pointer adjusted).  `pop` doesn't wipe out the source memory location either, but since the stack pointer is adjusted, the memory location that is popped is now below the stack pointer and so considered free to be overwritten.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push documents exactly what happens when a  `push` instruction executes; nothing more nothing less.  Each instruction just has its documented effect on architectural state.  Single-step that sequence in a debugger if you're not sure what will happen from simulating it in your head.  (And BTW, instructions generally leave a register or memory location unmodified after reading it, unless it's an explicit part of the instruction like `xchg`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through this step-by-step:

```
mov eax, 10    ; This assigns the value 10 to the register EAX
push eax       ; This puts the value of EAX onto the stack (a LIFO structure)
push 20        ; This puts the DWORD value 20 onto the stack
mov ecx, eax   ; This moves the value of the register EAX to the register ECX - the left hand side is the destination in x86 assembly with intel syntax
pop eax        ; This puts the top value of the stack into EAX and decreases the stackpointer to now point to the preceding item
```

The last instruction requires some additional info. I mentioned that the stack is a [LIFO data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). This stands for *Last-in-First-out*.

Therefore the value of EAX(=10) is pushed first onto the stack. In the next step the value 20 is pushed onto the stack. The `mov ecx, eax` instruction is meaningless for this task and can be ignored. Now, with the `pop eax`, the *last* item (remember LIFO) that has been pushed onto the stack is retrieved and put into the register EAX.

Hence the final answer is EAX=20.

Comment: Well left hand side is destination for normal/native or intel syntax for x86, but AT&T syntax right hand side is destination (left is not the destination for all x86 assembly).  The first instruction is the clue here that this is likely intel syntax and so ecx gets a copy of eax.  Fortunately that instruction is not relevant to the result so syntax style doesnt affect this question.  Only two of the instructions are relevant here and dont have intel vs AT&T issues.

Comment: @old_timer: I added a notice that the part in question is using _Intel syntax_. Otherwise, if the code would use AT&T syntax, it'd be flooded by `%` chars, so anybody could notice it easily.